# Define timeframe for month

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am writing a script where in it draws horizontal line for high and low of 5 min candle for daily session. It draws horizontal line for hourly candle of every monday and i am looking to draw similar high and low horizontal line for first day of the month. I did manage to define timeframe and opening session and timezone for daily and week but not able to get it for month. It would be great help if someone can help me with this. Below is code for daily and weekly i managed to get working.

```
openingRangePeriodd = "0915-0920"
openingRangePeriodw = "0915-1015"
daily = time(timeframe.period, str.format("{0}:1234567", openingRangePeriodd), timezone)
weekly = time(timeframe.period, str.format("{0}:2", openingRangePeriodw), timezone)
```

I tried differnet way of if its start of month or timeframe.ismonthly but not able to get it working.